# Configure helm--completing-read-default to pick the top match

Tags: helm, completing-read

I have the variable `completing-read-function` set to `helm--completing-read-default`. When an external package invokes `completing-read`, this gives `helm`-based completion. However, the default item picked by the `helm` completions buffer is the exact string that I have typed. In the `helm` window, this is the one at the top of all the selections and prefixed by a `?`. This isn't the behaviour I see with `helm-find-files` - the default selection there is the top match. So, if I have entered `abc` and there is a file named `xyzabc.txt` it will be selected(assuming its the top match). How do I get this behaviour with `helm--completing-read-default`? Note that I don't want to change the code of the external package which simply invokes `completing-read`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[I've asked helm's author years ago about this particular issue](https://github.com/emacs-helm/helm/issues/376).  Your described behaviour happens whenever a completing read does not specify that it requires an exact candidate match and is therefore not considered a helm bug.  That's why he recommends fixing these functions instead of providing an option to allow for this behaviour.